# Is it possible to create a <input> tag with only text instead of a button?

Tags: html, css

Can I show my `<input>` tag with only text, instead of a button? How would I do this?

Comment: What are you wanting the text to do? (E.g.: when clicked, post a form, etc.)

Comment: i want it to have the functionality remain, just that instead of button form, its in text form.

Comment: The most salient aspect of an `input` tag is its `type` attribute.  Is it a submit button you are asking about?  And is it that you want to post the form but have the link look like a standard hyperlink instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use CSS:

`<input style="vertical-align:bottom;overflow:visible; font-size:1em; display:inline;  margin:0; padding:0; border:0; border-bottom:1px solid blue; color:blue; cursor:pointer;" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: is there a way to make the background return white ? as of now its in button greylish color.

Comment: Add `background-color: White;` into the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

If I got your question right, you want to display a < input type="button" value="Foobar" /> with only the text and without the button-style.

```
<input type="button" value="Foobar" style="border: none; background: none; padding: 0;" />
```

Answer (score 3):

A button without the button is just a link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="do stuff;">My Text</a>
```

Comment: ya problem is i want to send a hidden value over, to dynamically creating a page with different content. Last i ask, i cant archieve a <hidden input> on a link. And i have no intention to have the header change

Comment: Put your form fields into a `<form>`. Then use your `<a>` to submit the form using Javascript.

Comment: does sounds good, tho i still prefer css. Thanks for advicing what are the other ways of doing it!